# Converting a Javascript String to an Integer problem

Tags: javascript

I have what I thought was a simple Javascript formula:

```
parseInt(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000).toString() + Date.now())
```

which I would expect to give me a number that is simply a random number concatenated (not added) with a timestamp.

When I look at just part of the code:  `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000).toString() + Date.now()` this does give me the string I would expect, such as `"9220291542844303075"`.

However, when I try converting this string into a number using `parseInt()` or `Number()`, those methods both return the desired number with three zeros at the end of it, such as: `9220291542844303075000`

How can I get the actual String I have converted to its same number so that `"9220291542844303075"` becomes `9220291542844303075` without the extra zeros, and why is the way I am doing it not working?

Comment: I suspect that you are overflowing the `int` in JS, which has a maximum of `9007199254740991`

Comment: The precision of float64 isn't enough to store such detailed numbers.